# Are there any KeyValue stores used by .NET?

Tags: c#, store, key-value

I am looking up keyvalue stores that support C#, but i found that most of them are implemented by Java. Could anybody recommend some to me? It would be super if it is very light-weight, i.e., appearing as a library. thanks!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777103/what-nosql-solutions-are-out-there-for-net.

Comment: Are you talking about Certificate Key Value Store?

Comment: We're all very curious what you mean by a KeyValue store :).

Comment: Do you want an in-memory key-value store or persistent?

Comment: https://github.com/koculu/ZoneTree ZoneTree is a persistent, high-performance, transactional, and ACID-compliant ordered key-value database for .NET. It can operate in memory or on local/cloud storage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are tons, depending on your requirements.

Another you can consider is [System.Runtime.Caching namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997357.aspx), which has been added to .NET 4.0.

Answer (score 10):

```
Dictionary<key,Value>  

               http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx

KeyValuePair<string, string>

              http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5tbh8a42.aspx
```

Answer (score 10):

If you want an in-process, persistent key-value store (like Berkeley Db) then take a look at the PersistentDictionary which is part of the ManagedEsent project. A persistent dictionary looks like a normal dictionary but is backed by a database. If you build from the current sources then you will get Linq support, which lets you do queries.

Answer (score 6):

If you mean a NoSQL store, [What NoSQL solutions are out there for .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777103/what-nosql-solutions-are-out-there-for-net) has a list of these.

Answer (score 3):

is this what you mean by a key Value pair..like a hashtable()

```
Hashtable = ht = new HashTable();
```

or

```
Dictionary<double,string> d1 = new Dictionary<double,string>();
```

or

```
Dictionary<String,string> d2 = new  Dictionary<string,string>();
```

etc.

Answer (score 3):

```
>  I am looking up keyvalue stores that support C#
```

If you're looking for a native .NET key value store then try [NCache](http://www.alachisoft.com/ncache/). Its built using C#. There are none other i think.

Its offers much more than just a simple [.net key value store](http://blogs.alachisoft.com/ncache/key-value-store-vs-distributed-cache/). You can stick to just keeping keys and values in it.

```
Cache cache = NCache.InitializeCache("CacheName");
cache.Add("Key", "Value");
object value = cache.Get("Key");
```

Answer (score 2):

[Redis](http://code.google.com/p/redis/) is a excellent one. And there is amazing c# redis client [ServiceStackRedis](http://code.google.com/p/servicestack/wiki/ServiceStackRedis) also available. Its very lightweight.

And if you want to try redis on windows, you can find the windows version [here](http://code.google.com/p/servicestack/downloads/list)

Answer (score 1):

GetCache is a very simple key-value in-memory cache developed in .Net 4.5. 
Server and client library can be downloaded fron Nuget.

http://www.nuget.org/packages/GetCacheServer/

http://www.nuget.org/packages/GetCacheClient/

Answer (score 1):

FASTER - A fast concurrent persistent key-value store and log, in C# and C++

https://microsoft.github.io/FASTER/